# Abbreviations in the Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: dictionary

The Ubuntu Software Center uses lots of abbreviations and words that I do not know, because I am not a programmer. Ninety-nine out of a hundred times when I look at information about a program with an interesting name I do not understand a word of what is written there. Is there a dictionary or a thesaurus somewhere where I can find these things?

Answer (score 1):

Visit the [Ubuntu Glossary wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/glossary). The Glossary of Terms in the Ubuntu Glossary wiki is meant to be an information resource and reference of commonly and uncommonly used terms, arranged alphabetically.

There are many other sources of information about decoding abbreviations and acronyms, etc. on the web, however the advantage of the Ubuntu Glossary wiki is that it is *Ubuntu-specific*.